# SpeechRecognizer is not available on my android emulator. Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-emulator, speech-recognition

I am new to android application development and I am trying to create a voice assistant in Kotlin. When I try to use my microphone it seems that my SpeechRecognizer doesn't work. I followed the directions of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a7-Z9awsods&t=318s), but when I test my app on emulator it seems that SpeechRecognizer isn't avaiable. I also tried [this issue](https://github.com/csdcorp/speech_to_text/issues/159) on github, but it didn't help me.

The result is always the same. I always get the text string I wrote in case the `SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable` is not available.

Here is what i have tried to do:

- **Add all permition to my application from android settings**
- **Enable the microphone from emulator settings**

Here is my scrips:

***AndroidManifest.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.firstkotlinproject">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.speech.RecognitionService"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.FirstKotlinProject"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

***activity_main.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#525252">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_to_change"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFA500"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:text="Hello"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_to_click"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_to_change"
        android:textColor="#FFA500"
        android:backgroundTint="#000"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

***MainActivity***

```
package com.example.firstkotlinproject

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val requestCodeDefoult = 102
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        button_to_click.setOnClickListener {
            askSpeechInput()
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == requestCodeDefoult && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val result :ArrayList<String>? = data?.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS)
            textView_to_change.text = result?.get(0).toString()
        }
    }
    private fun buttonPressed() :Boolean {
        var result = false
        if (button_to_click.isPressed) {
            result = true
        }
        return result
    }

    private fun askSpeechInput() {
        if (!SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(this)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Speech recognition is not avaiable!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else if (!buttonPressed()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Press the button to speak", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            val i = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
            i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM)
            i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.ITALIAN)
            i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Say something...")
            startActivity(i)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Emulator doesn't necessarily pick up the sound. It would be better to test on a physical device. I have built many Assistants and I have always had to test on a physical device

Comment: in my emulator it supports mic, i enabled it in the emulator setitings, and i can give input using voice using gboard, but when i try speechrecognizer, its not working, isRecognitionAvailable is always returning false