# SpeechRecognizer not working in Wear Emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, wear-os, voice-recognition

I am trying to create a custom voice recognition page, with custom UI, but

```
SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(this) is always returning false.
```

I can Input using gboard voice prompt and the mic is working fine, when i tried using RecognizerIntent it was also working.

but SpeechRecognizer is not working , I tried it on a LG wear and it was working fine there.
but in emulator, even with working mic, the checking **isRecognitionAvailable** is always returning false.

*Update*
Its not supporting when i select Android 11, ist working fine when I use Android Pie Wear OS Image, and the **isRecognitionAvailable** is actually returning true, and everything works fine. but i also want the gboard to support, which is not available in android pie versions

Comment: This is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73457986/speechrecognizer-is-not-available-on-my-android-emulator-kotlin

Comment: I believe it isn't supported on emulators.

Comment: I checked the all other questions here, but i didnt get any solution so far, 
i been on this for hours, and then i created another emulator, which is Oreo (the first one was android 11) and its returning true now, but when i initialize the speech recogniser, its showing some google service is stopped working, i updated the google play service on wear, but still same issue

Comment: Its working fine in When I use Wear OS Pie emulator, it supports, Speech Recogniser, but its not working in Android 11 (latest i can find)

Comment: If you think it should be supported, raise a bug at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192708&template=840533